# NSDateFormatter is not converting correctly NSString to NSdate

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

here is code i am using for conversion

```
NSString * dateString = @"9/12/2011";
NSDateFormatter *serverDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[serverDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *serverDate = [serverDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[serverDateFormatter release];
```

And output is
2011-09-11 19:00:00 +0000

But i just want to convert that nsstring into nsdate with the same format 9/12/2011

Comment: I think you'd need `@"09/12/2011"` for that format.

Comment: not true, just tried it and it is working fine.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is the default format in which iOS prints the date in log. And the date printed is **5 hours earlier than the original date because** of the the time zone offset adjustment. Your time zone seems to be `+05:00`. Just making sure that `9` is the month, `12` is enough here. If so, the above code is working fine.

Comment: Plus a side note: A NSDate has NO format at all. It just saves time.

Comment: @TalaT just check my code that will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code because I run that code successfully.

```
NSString * dateString = @"9/12/2011";
NSDateFormatter *serverDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[serverDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *serverDate = [serverDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",serverDate);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *st = (NSDate *)[dateFormat stringFromDate:serverDate];
NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Its return 9/12/2011 so try it.

Comment: Why are you converting a string `@"9/12/2011"` to another same string `@"9/12/2011"` (How can you directly cast a NSString to NSDate)? Why don't you just use the string `dateString`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
     NSString * dateString = @"9/12/2011";
NSDateFormatter *serverDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[serverDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *serverDate = [serverDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",serverDate);

NSDateFormatter *tempDate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[tempDate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
   NSDate *date=(NSDate *)[tempDate stringFromDate:serverDate];
NSLog(@"%@",date);

[tempDate release];
[serverDateFormatter release];
```

hope this will help you..

Comment: No its returns 12/09/2011 but user wants in this format 9/12/2011

Comment: so use [tempDate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

Answer (score 0):

Set this properties to your `NSDateFormatter` :

```
[serverDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[serverDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```